# Should updates to a JUNG graph be done on the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graph, jung

I have a JUNG graph that is constantly be updated (new vertices, removing vertices, and updating existing vertices).  All of this work is done in a bunch of custom classes that run on their own thread waiting for updates from an external source, then updating appropriately.

I now want to visualize the graph, so I retrieve a reference to the graph and set it in a Layout which is given to a VisualizationViewer.  When updates come in, they are processed in the other thread, then I call VisualizationViewer.repaint() to refresh the graph.

My question is, should I be doing all the work updating the graph object on the EDT?  Or is it alright to do the work in a separate thread, then just call vv.repaint() like I'm doing now?  Not sure if helpful/related, but while most of the updates are coming from an external source, the user can still manually delete things in the graph through the GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan's answer is incorrect, you do not need to update the graph object on the EDT.

Your `VisualizationViewer` should always be on the EDT, yes, but using functions like `addVertex` or `addEdge` can be called from any thread. The important thing to remember is that you cannot call `vv.repaint()` from the same thread that you are updating on.

I achieve this by adding a `PropertyChangeListener` on the `JPanel` holding the `VisualizationViewer`. This listens to changes in the graph and calls repaint accordingly.

Comment: You're saying exactly what I'm saying, updating the GUI must be done on the EDT except that in your answer, you keep the `repaint`, the GUI update, on the EDT and that is suboptimal... just change the label on the EDT instead for example, or add the vertex on the EDT.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused by Jon's comment.

Comment: As long as you call `repaint` from you `VisualizationViewer` on the `EDT`, it will work. This answer is basically saying the same thing as mine. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, we are saying the same thing after your edit - but, initially, you stated, "Every updates must be done on the EDT.". That's the part that wasn't correct since it seemed like the OP wanted to know where they could update the model (as Fernando summarizes).

Answer (score 0):

Most GUI updates must be done on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). It would be better to do the changes on it directly and avoid calling `repaint` unless it is absolutely necessary.

To be sure the code to update the GUI is called on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), you can do that kinda of code :

```
final JLabel label = yourLabel;
Runnable code = new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    label.setText("SomeText");    
  }
};

if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
  code.run();
} else {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(code);
}
```

That way, you don't have to worry from which thread the code is called from and it will update the label.

Edit :
To clarify, what you could do is, when you want to update your graph, is to make sure the call to your `VisualizationViewer` `repaint` method is done like this

```
final VisualizationViewer viewer = w;
Runnable code = new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    viewer.repaint();    
  }
};

if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
  code.run();
} else {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(code);
}
```

Comment: It would still be ok to return the reference to the graph when I'm creating the GUI, but just make sure when I'm updating the graph after that point to do it on the EDT with invokeLater?

Comment: Yes it would, as long it is done on the EDT. I still recommend to avoid using `repaint` as it does a lot more than just the needed changes.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying now.  After updating things on the EDT it will refresh what is necessary when its exiting the runnable?  So by changing things on the EDT is better since calling `repaint` does a lot of extra stuff not needed?

Comment: Yes, doing specific GUI changes on the EDT will be more efficient than calling `repaint` on a whole bunch of components that might not need to be repainted..